# Does Google Cloud Vision OCR API have better accuracy and performance than Tesseract OCR API

Tags: tesseract, google-cloud-vision

I have integrated Google Cloud Vision API in my java application for text recognition from complex formatted documents. One of my colleague suggested to use "Tesseract API".Can anyone please give difference between these two API's.And which is better in terms of accuracy or have any advantage over other.TIA

Comment: Yes it is. I don't have any source and links to define my answer. What I have is I have used both:
It is easy to implement, Available offline, no need to train your own language, small in size, 30% more accurate results, Better documentations and examples available.  

Drawbacks
Limited languages, no RTL language yet, in mobile devices it is dependent on play service version.

Answer (score 2):

I have used both of them.
Google Vision is much faster than Tesseract and If it was a year back then the accuracy was also better.

Tesseract lately adapted LSTM with preferred language choice and trained data which when optimized could get faster about 2X or more. But surely it can not get faster than Google vision unless they start supporting CUDA.

Regarding accuracy I have tested both of them with best and worst document images and were Google Vision landed on 66.6% accuracy, Tesseract went to 82% which is high enough for me.

If you prefer accuracy Tesseract is a winner and if you prefer time Google Vision is the best option.

Also there are couple of other CUDA supported projects which may be better than them.

Answer (score 1):

Google Vision OCR is paid and it better than tesseract, while tesseract is completely free and an open-source project.

you can read these block for understanding the differences:

1.https://www.reddit.com/r/computervision/comments/74qcqv/tesseract_or_google_vision_api_for_image_ocr/

2.https://dataturks.com/blog/compare-image-text-recognition-apis.php